# Is it possible to start a read-only transaction with QSqlDatabase and QOCI Plugin on a Oracle 19c database?

Tags: oracle, qt, transactions, qt5

i'm trying to start a read-only transaction thru the QSqlDatabase Framework.

I'm using Qt 5.15.4 with QOCI plugin built against OCI 12.2 (don't ask ) and Oracle DB 19c. This setup ist basically working.

What i have tried:

```
// init database connection
auto db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(QLatin1String("QOCI"));
assert(db.isValid()); // OK
db.setHostName(QString(test));
//...set more connection options
assert(db.open()); // OK

// create test table
db.exec(QLatin1String("CREATE TABLE foobar (test INT)"));
assert(!db.lastError().isValid()); // OK

// start read-only transaction: variant a
db.exec(QLatin1String("SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY"));
assert(!db.lastError().isValid()); // OK

// INSERT not allowed -> should fail with ORA-01456
db.exec(QLatin1String("INSERT INTO foobar (test) VALUES (1)"));
assert(db.lastError().isValid()); // FAIL no error ORA-01456

// start read-only transaction: variant b
db.transaction();
assert(!db.lastError().isValid()); // OK

db.exec(QLatin1String("SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY"));
asert(!db.lastError().isValid());  // FAIL with: "ORA-01453: SET TRANSACTION must be first statement of transaction"
```

If i change `OCI_TRANS_READWRITE` to `OCI_TRANS_READONLY` for `OCITransStart()` in `QOCIDriver::beginTransaction()` as a test only, ORA-01456 is thrown after `QSqlDatabase::transaction()` and a `INSERT`-Statement.

Is there any chance to start a read-only transaction in Qt with OCI without patching/expanding Qt?

Comment: I am not an Oracle expert but reading [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems047.htm#:~:text=The%20SET%20TRANSACTION%20statement%20begins,users%20update%20the%20same%20tables.), it seems `SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY` does start a transaction but you use it as if to alter an existing transaction. You should remove the previous `db.transaction();` since it conflicts with your statement.

Comment: @Atmo: This is done in variant b and fails with ORA-0153 ;(

Comment: @Atmo Sorry, i misunderstood your first comment, nevertheless, if i don't start a transaction the  `SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY` command does not have any effect (variant a), even if i use a combination on commit or rollback before. BTW i have no problem to achive a read only transaction with the Sql Developer. IMO it is a missing feature in Qt5

Comment: What do you mean by *command does not have any effect*? Your only comment for variant a is `OK` when starting the transaction and `FAIL` (which is the expected behavior) for the insert command. What is your problem, really (question to be answered by editing your question, not by typing a command)?

Comment: I repeat what I said in my first comment, `SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY` **IS** what starts the transaction, as proven by the fact the `INSERT` in variant a fails with `ORA-01456`. Why else would it fail this way if not for the read-only transaction having started?

Comment: @Atmo Your right, i have a copy&paste error in my question. Sorry for that. The `INSERT` Statement is executed without any error after setting `SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY`.